# Securely Exposing C# REST API to scripting language such as Python

Tags: c#, python, rest, security

My C# REST API are called from an AngularJS web app. I secure the Web API by authenticating the user and ensuring the user is part of a specific windows group.

Now the customer would like the option of calling the API from scripts (Python). How do I implement this?  Should I just get them to pass username and password as part of the json call?

Comment: Why not use the same authentication mechanism as for web?

Comment: I'm using cookies and an authorisation from another server that expects it from a browser. It's just not feasible

Comment: Nothing that python http libraries can't handle. But if you want it to be simpler, HTTP basic auth and openid/OAuth are pretty common for API auth

Comment: Can you post some code showing how exactly you are currently performing authentication and authorization?

Comment: This question is too broad. You can use a lot of different authentication schemes: tokens, basic auth, plain username and password, even current scheme with cookies (python script can work with cookies too). You can read about authentication schemes for C# web api in many many places over internet.

Comment: You can easily wrap your .NET calls from Python using pythonnet.

Comment: you are using any webframework ? can you specify the framework you are using (c#), then one could reply with a proper answer to you

Comment: Cookeis are just sent in the http header. Can you not just manage the header manually via the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use exactly the same authentication method you are currently using.

Here is a basic example using python (untested):

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
s = requests.Session()

# Make the initial authentication request from a session object
s.get('https://omg.wtf/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))

# All subsequent requests from that session will include any cookies set in the initial response
r = s.get('http://omg.wtf/911')
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Is it possible to redirect to the python script and set a cookie?

Comment: what do you mean redirect? the cookie is store in s = requests.Session()
you can always just make new requests using the cookie/session.

Comment: Tweak @SeanThorburn's original code so that the initial request is also made from the session object. That object will remember any cookies set in the initial response, and send those cookie values in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 5):

If you can augment headers in Python easily, I would suggest that you use token authentication. Microsoft does not provide this type of auth directly, but via OWIN project. It's not that hard to use, but you'll need to learn how stuff works first. There is a very good and comprehensive tutorial [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).

Basically you obtain a token (that is valid for some period of time) by providing a username/password. This token is encrypted/signed which means your backend will trust is without the need of validating username/password on each request (which is costly). Then you need to add this token to a header `Authorization bearer token` or something similar for each request. Alternatively I think you can have the token in the cookie to maintain backwards consistency if you like.

I would suggest that you use the same mechanism in Angular as well, since you can easily add an interceptor there and avoid cookies and CSRF potential troubles with them.